# QR scanning Issue in Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code, galaxy

I have created an app which can scan QR code, It works well with all the Android devices excluding **Samsung Galaxy s4**. 
App does not scan any QR code while using Galaxy s4 device. 
Now as this Galaxy s4 having Android 4.2.2 version, I also verified my app in other devices having same Android version (4.2.2) like Nexus-4 and it works fine with it. 
Is any other hardware used to scan QR code in Galaxy s4? 
Need help to solve this weird problem!
Following is the code i used in my app.
**CameraManager.java**

```
/**
 * This object wraps the Camera service object and expects to be the only one talking to it. The
 * implementation encapsulates the steps needed to take preview-sized images, which are used for
 * both preview and decoding.
 *
 * @author dswitkin@google.com (Daniel Switkin)
 */
public final class CameraManager {

  private static final String TAG = CameraManager.class.getSimpleName();

  private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 240;
  private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 240;
  private static final int MAX_FRAME_WIDTH = 480;
  private static final int MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT = 360;

  private static CameraManager cameraManager;

  static final int SDK_INT; // Later we can use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
  static {
    int sdkInt;
    try {
      sdkInt = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      // Just to be safe
      sdkInt = 10000;
    }
    SDK_INT = sdkInt;
  }

  private final Context context;
  private final CameraConfigurationManager configManager;
  private Camera camera;
  private Rect framingRect;
  private Rect framingRectInPreview;
  private boolean initialized;
  private boolean previewing;
  private boolean reverseImage;
  private final boolean useOneShotPreviewCallback;
  /**
   * Preview frames are delivered here, which we pass on to the registered handler. Make sure to
   * clear the handler so it will only receive one message.
   */
  private final PreviewCallback previewCallback;

  /** Autofocus callbacks arrive here, and are dispatched to the Handler which requested them. */
  private final AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback;

  /**
   * Initializes this static object with the Context of the calling Activity.
   *
   * @param context The Activity which wants to use the camera.
   */
  public static void init(Context context) {
    if (cameraManager == null) {
      cameraManager = new CameraManager(context);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the CameraManager singleton instance.
   *
   * @return A reference to the CameraManager singleton.
   */
  public static CameraManager get() {
    return cameraManager;
  }

  private CameraManager(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    this.configManager = new CameraConfigurationManager(context);

    // Camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback() has a race condition in Cupcake, so we use the older
    // Camera.setPreviewCallback() on 1.5 and earlier. For Donut and later, we need to use
    // the more efficient one shot callback, as the older one can swamp the system and cause it
    // to run out of memory. We can't use SDK_INT because it was introduced in the Donut SDK.
    useOneShotPreviewCallback = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) > 3; // 3 = Cupcake

    previewCallback = new PreviewCallback(configManager, useOneShotPreviewCallback);
    autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback();
  }

  /**
   * Opens the camera driver and initializes the hardware parameters.
   *
   * @param holder The surface object which the camera will draw preview frames into.
   * @throws IOException Indicates the camera driver failed to open.
   */
  public void openDriver(SurfaceHolder holder) throws IOException {
    if (camera == null) {
      camera = Camera.open();
      if (camera == null) {
        throw new IOException();
      }
    }
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    if (!initialized) {
      initialized = true;
      configManager.initFromCameraParameters(camera);
    }
    configManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(camera);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    reverseImage = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_REVERSE_IMAGE, false);
    if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_FRONT_LIGHT, false)) {
      FlashlightManager.enableFlashlight();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Closes the camera driver if still in use.
   */
  public void closeDriver() {
    if (camera != null) {
      FlashlightManager.disableFlashlight();
      camera.release();
      camera = null;

      // Make sure to clear these each time we close the camera, so that any scanning rect
      // requested by intent is forgotten.
      framingRect = null;
      framingRectInPreview = null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Asks the camera hardware to begin drawing preview frames to the screen.
   */
  public void startPreview() {
    if (camera != null && !previewing) {
      camera.startPreview();
      previewing = true;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Tells the camera to stop drawing preview frames.
   */
  public void stopPreview() {
    if (camera != null && previewing) {
      if (!useOneShotPreviewCallback) {
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
      }
      camera.stopPreview();
      previewCallback.setHandler(null, 0);
      autoFocusCallback.setHandler(null, 0);
      previewing = false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * A single preview frame will be returned to the handler supplied. The data will arrive as byte[]
   * in the message.obj field, with width and height encoded as message.arg1 and message.arg2,
   * respectively.
   *
   * @param handler The handler to send the message to.
   * @param message The what field of the message to be sent.
   */
  public void requestPreviewFrame(Handler handler, int message) {
    if (camera != null && previewing) {
      previewCallback.setHandler(handler, message);
      if (useOneShotPreviewCallback) {
        camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
      } else {
        camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Asks the camera hardware to perform an autofocus.
   *
   * @param handler The Handler to notify when the autofocus completes.
   * @param message The message to deliver.
   */
  public void requestAutoFocus(Handler handler, int message) {
    if (camera != null && previewing) {
      autoFocusCallback.setHandler(handler, message);
      //Log.d(TAG, "Requesting auto-focus callback");
      camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Calculates the framing rect which the UI should draw to show the user where to place the
   * barcode. This target helps with alignment as well as forces the user to hold the device
   * far enough away to ensure the image will be in focus.
   *
   * @return The rectangle to draw on screen in window coordinates.
   */
  public Rect getFramingRect() {
    if (framingRect == null) {
      if (camera == null) {
        return null;
      }
      Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
      int width = screenResolution.x * 3 / 4;
      if (width < MIN_FRAME_WIDTH) {
        width = MIN_FRAME_WIDTH;
      } else if (width > MAX_FRAME_WIDTH) {
        width = MAX_FRAME_WIDTH;
      }
      int height = screenResolution.y * 3 / 4;
      if (height < MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT) {
        height = MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT;
      } else if (height > MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT) {
        height = MAX_FRAME_HEIGHT;
      }
      int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - width) / 2;
      int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - height) / 2;
      framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset + height);
      Log.d(TAG, "Calculated framing rect: " + framingRect);
    }
    return framingRect;
  }

  /**
   * Like {@link #getFramingRect} but coordinates are in terms of the preview frame,
   * not UI / screen.
   */
  public Rect getFramingRectInPreview() {
    if (framingRectInPreview == null) {
      Rect rect = new Rect(getFramingRect());
      Point cameraResolution = configManager.getCameraResolution();
      Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();

      /* updated to allow for portrait instead of landscape 
      rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
      rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
      rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
      rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y; */

      rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
      rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.x;
      rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
      rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.y;
      framingRectInPreview = rect;
    }
    return framingRectInPreview;
  }

  /**
   * Allows third party apps to specify the scanning rectangle dimensions, rather than determine
   * them automatically based on screen resolution.
   *
   * @param width The width in pixels to scan.
   * @param height The height in pixels to scan.
   */
  public void setManualFramingRect(int width, int height) {
    Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
    if (width > screenResolution.x) {
      width = screenResolution.x;
    }
    if (height > screenResolution.y) {
      height = screenResolution.y;
    }
    int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - width) / 2;
    int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - height) / 2;
    framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset + height);
    Log.d(TAG, "Calculated manual framing rect: " + framingRect);
    framingRectInPreview = null;
  }

  /**
   * A factory method to build the appropriate LuminanceSource object based on the format
   * of the preview buffers, as described by Camera.Parameters.
   *
   * @param data A preview frame.
   * @param width The width of the image.
   * @param height The height of the image.
   * @return A PlanarYUVLuminanceSource instance.
   */
  public PlanarYUVLuminanceSource buildLuminanceSource(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
    Rect rect = getFramingRectInPreview();
    int previewFormat = configManager.getPreviewFormat();
    String previewFormatString = configManager.getPreviewFormatString();

    switch (previewFormat) {
      // This is the standard Android format which all devices are REQUIRED to support.
      // In theory, it's the only one we should ever care about.
      case PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP:
      // This format has never been seen in the wild, but is compatible as we only care
      // about the Y channel, so allow it.
      case PixelFormat.YCbCr_422_SP:
        return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, rect.left, rect.top,
            rect.width(), rect.height(), reverseImage);
      default:
        // The Samsung Moment incorrectly uses this variant instead of the 'sp' version.
        // Fortunately, it too has all the Y data up front, so we can read it.
        if ("yuv420p".equals(previewFormatString)) {
          return new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, rect.left, rect.top,
              rect.width(), rect.height(), reverseImage);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported picture format: " +
        previewFormat + '/' + previewFormatString);
  }

}
```

**PreviewCallback.java**

```
final class PreviewCallback implements Camera.PreviewCallback {

  private static final String TAG = PreviewCallback.class.getSimpleName();

  private final CameraConfigurationManager configManager;
  private final boolean useOneShotPreviewCallback;
  private Handler previewHandler;
  private int previewMessage;

  PreviewCallback(CameraConfigurationManager configManager, boolean useOneShotPreviewCallback) {
    this.configManager = configManager;
    this.useOneShotPreviewCallback = useOneShotPreviewCallback;
  }

  void setHandler(Handler previewHandler, int previewMessage) {
    this.previewHandler = previewHandler;
    this.previewMessage = previewMessage;
  }

  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Point cameraResolution = configManager.getCameraResolution();
    if (!useOneShotPreviewCallback) {
      camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    }
    if (previewHandler != null) {
      Message message = previewHandler.obtainMessage(previewMessage, cameraResolution.x,
          cameraResolution.y, data);
      message.sendToTarget();
      previewHandler = null;
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "Got preview callback, but no handler for it");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: If it works on 'every other device' it might be "too localized". I might suggest looking into Galaxy forums as well.

Comment: @BobbyDigital .. i already gone through Galaxy forums & other sites but no help found regarding this issue..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set camera preview format before you start the preview mode. *Yes, Android documentation says that the default format should be PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP=17, but I have seen some devices that don't follow this rule. And some use* **[yuyv](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUY2)** *packed 422 format, which does not have a luminance block to copy, as your code does, but requires reshuffling of the bytes.* It would also be wise to set the preview width and height. It is most likely that you don't need more than VGA resolution to scan QR codes.

**Update:** on my device, the default preview frame is 1920x1080 pixels. Note that this is a 16:9, not 4:3 aspect ratio.  I see in your code some reference to hardcoded 4:3, but if this assumption is used to interpret the QR code, this alone could be a reason for failure.

Comment: yes you are right, In my code aspect ratio is 4:3 and Galaxy s4 requires 16:9... it might be reason for failure.. So now how can we set it dynamically ?

Comment: Open camera, getParameters, setPreviewSize 640x480, setParameters, startPreview, profit!

Comment: Thnx alex there was an issue because of such hardcoded resolution, I changed it and set device's default resolution, So now it working.. and now catch your profit :) ... but still I had to hold the phone further away from the QR code to scan... Is it possible here to control focusing system of camera ?

Comment: @NiravDangi after going through this code I did the changes as said by Alex Cohn. Even I'm facing the issue of scanning holder away from the codes. Did you arrive at any solution for this. Can you please help me out.